# How to Convert Binary to Hex

Tags: binary, hex, byte, bit

So I have a binary number but there's only 11 bits.

The number: 10111101110

I need to convert this to hexadecimal.

I divide into three parts: 101 1110 1110

I know the last two parts are EE

The part with three bits is catching me. If i add a zero to make it 0101 its 6
or do I add a zero at the end to make it 1010 giving me B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it on the front, so that the result is 0101

Answer (score 1):

You make leading bits 0, in front of your 3 bits, for accurate representation, otherwise you are shifting bits to left which will multiply your number.

Answer (score 1):

Bits that are not there must have the value 0, any number in any base can always be thought of as having any number of leading zeros.

If you're doing the conversion by hand, you can of course just stop when you run out of digits, there's nothing forcing you to always convert any particular number of bits at a time.